# postgresql pg library taking windows username instead of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, strapi, pg

i am using pg lib in strapi application, where initially it creates postgres connection using correct postgresql username(postgres), database name(strapi_db) and password(postgres) but after login it changed it to connect using my windows 10 username(rayappan.a, and database as rayappan.a). it seems strange to me because i never configured anywhere to use my windows credentials for POSTGRESQL connection. please any one tell me how to fix username connection issue

Regards,
Rayappan Antoniraj

Comment: You are going to have to provide some example code if you want anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING . It states that username:

> Defaults to be the same as the operating system name of the user running the application."

The database name:

> Defaults to be the same as the user name.

So it seems a new connection with parameters not set is made.

Comment: module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "bookshelf",
      connection : "default",
      settings: {
        client: "postgres",
        host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
        port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
        database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "postgres"),
        username: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "postgres"),
        password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "postgres")
      },
      options: {},
    },
  },
});

Comment: this is my config/database.js file contents in strapi application

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have experience with strapi. If you compare your config to https://strapi.io/blog/postgre-sql-and-strapi-setup you'll see you have a `connection : "default"` in your default connection. Might it be the cause of your problems ?

Comment: I removed connection: "default" but still getting the same issue.

Comment: module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "bookshelf",
      connection: {
        client: "postgres",
        host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
        port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
        database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "postgres"),
        user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "postgres"),
        username: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "postgres"),
        password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "postgres"),
        schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"),
      },
   options: {},
 },
  },
});

Comment: this is new database.js file

Comment: in the example (https://strapi.io/blog/postgre-sql-and-strapi-setup) connection object containing all the connection parameters is `settings` and it is `connection` in your code. How did you come up with the structure of your database.js file? Also you have `user` and `username` - only `username` is needed... I suggest you find documentation or a working example and compare to your program.